# How to write list of htm files to excel format with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

So far I use pandas for read list of HTM files but I do not Know how to write all files in list to xlsx format.

This is the code that I use for read files.

```
import pandas as pd 
import os 
import glob

path = os.getcwd()
htm_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(r'D:/Phenology/02Climate/', "*.htm")) 
filesname = htm_files[count].split(".")[0] + ".xlsx"

for f in htm_files:
    df = pd.read_html(f)
    display(df)
```

I have try this for writing but it did not work.

```
df1 = df.to_excel(r"D:/Phenology/02Climate/Excel/" + filename)
```

And error is `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_excel'`

Comment: Looks like your `df` is a `list` instead of a dataframe. Can you please do `print(type(df))` to confirm this?

Comment: Yes, It's list.

Answer (score 1):

[pandas.read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) retuns a list of dataframes and not a dataframe.